# My List Widget of a type model can't be assigned to the same type

Tags: flutter

***The argument type 'List (where WallpaperModel is defined in d:\Flutter Projects\felexo\felexo\lib\Model\wallpapers-model.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List (where WallpaperModel is defined in d:\Flutter Projects\felexo\felexo\lib\model\wallpapers-model.dart)'.***

```
List<WallpaperModel> wallpapers;
getCateogryWallpapers() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            "https://api.pexels.com/v1/search/?page=2&per_page=$noOfImages&query=wallpapers"),
        headers: {"Authorization": apiKey});
    // print(response.body.toString());
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    jsonData["photos"].forEach((element) {
      WallpaperModel wallpaperModel = new WallpaperModel();
      wallpaperModel = WallpaperModel.fromMap(jsonData);
      wallpapers.add(wallpaperModel);
    });
    imagesLoaded = true;
    setState(() {});
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          widget.color,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
        ),
      ),
      body: wallpaperSearchGrid(
          wallpapers: wallpapers, context: context, uid: user.uid),
    );
  }
```

Comment: That can be done but the error is that the same type of data is not being assigned to each other

Comment: These are not the same types. Classes are named the same, but as you said - they are defined in different files. What's the question here? What are you trying to do?

Comment: They are not two different files. They are the same files.

Comment: It's fixed. Flutter was importing the wrong file for some reason when it automatically imports the required dart file. Had to manually import later on.